# Included How to write an image from a particular index of iCarousel to a file?

Tags: ios, iphone, file, uiimageview, icarousel

I'm using `iCarousel` View in my app, here I'm display numerous image as slideshow,

I want to write a particular image at a particular index of icarousel to a file (NSDocument directory). Please help to fix this.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{


    NSURL *url;
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"BASICDEALER_IMAGE"]==YES)
    {
               url= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",IMAGE_REPOSITORY,[_mArImageURLs objectAtIndex:index]]];
    }
    else{
               url= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_mArImageURLs objectAtIndex:index]]];
    }

    // 2
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadPhotoTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                               downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
   {
        // 3

       UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
       Placeholdimg =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:downloadedImage];

     }];

    // 4    
    [downloadPhotoTask resume];


    [view addSubview:Placeholdimg];
    Placeholdimg.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    view.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
     return view;

}
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Hello BSS & welcome to [so]!  A good question will usually show some relevant code so that way a great answer can be customized to help you the most.  The code I'd very much like to see would be your `iCarouselDataSource` methods that you have implemented.